# 1120 :access of undefined property ssGlobals

Tags: flash

I have this problem 1120 :access of undefined property ssGlobals in compiler,

```
//the code---------------------------

video_u2_3.skin = ssGlobals.ssStartDir + "\\video/SkinUnderAllNoCaption.swf";

video_u2_3.source = ssGlobals.ssStartDir + "\\video/unite_2/3.mp4";
```

Comment: The code doesn't show how ssGlobals is being created and what context it has. Did you try to try to trace its value or use the debugger to see the exact values?

Comment: here is the whole code

Comment: I just googled for "ssGlobals" and realized that you are actually asking about SWF Studio (http://www.northcode.com/v3/help/SWFStudio/ssGlobals_%20Overview.html). I don't have any experience with SWF Studio, sorry.